# ProxyPass if RewriteCond is TRUE

Tags: proxypass, rewritecond

At proxypass configuration file I have written this line

```
ProxyPass /directory/ ajp://localhost:8009/directory/
```

It works perfectly

At htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^seconddirectory/(.*)$ http://domain.com.localhost/directory/$1 [P]
```

P flag implies L.

This works too

If I use only [L] it works too. Anyway, will match with ProxyPass.

But I want the Proxy redirects via AJP only if a referer contains /action if not you can't use the ProxyPass

I tried to make a condition with RewriteCond

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}% !/action
RewriteRule .? - [S=2]
  RewriteRule ^seconddirectory/(.*)$ https://domain.com.localhost/directory/$1 [L]
  RewriteRule .? - [S=1]
RewriteRule ^seconddirectory/(.*)$ https://domain.com.localhost/404 [L]
```

If (referer no contains /action), in this case, is skipping 2 lines and is redirected to a 404 page

If the URL is

https://domain.com.localhost/seconddirectory/anything

I'm being redirected to https://domain.com.localhost/404

This is correct

If referer contains /action

I'm not beign redirected to https://domain.com.localhost/directory/$1

This is the referer where I come from https://domain.com.localhost/controller.php/module/atoken/action (referer)

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is the `[P]` flag of `RewriteRule`.  Something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^alias.domain.com$ [I]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://myinternalserver.com/$1 [P,L]
```

Comment: I had changed the question but I have a little problem with the RewriteCond to match with the RewriteRule wtih the [P] flag. But this flag Is a posible solution to match a condition before execute the proxypass. Without this flag the ProxyPass will match first and the condition could not be executed before. Thank You